# Python XML parser - break down to class and functions

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing

I've created recently python script parsing multiple xml files matching given pattern and writing the results into the .csv file (see code below).
I would like to break the code below into the class and functions, something like this:
Class:
Function 1 -> loads filepaths into the list;
Function 2 -> writes the results into the .csv file

Any suggestions how to do it? Many thanks in advance for your help.

```
#
# Import Python modules
#
import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#
# Define rootpath and pattern
#
rootpath = '/Users/USER_ONE/XML_Test_Data'
pattern = 'data-*'
#
# Search for files in directory and add the selection into list
#
List = []
for root, dors, files in os.walk(rootpath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        List.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

print('')
print('=====================================')
print('List of files matching the criteria')
print('=====================================')
print('')
#
# Print files matching the criteria one by one
#
count = 0
for item in List:
    print(item)
    count += 1
print('')
print(str(count) +' files retrieved')
#
print('')
print('=====================================')
print('System now extracts data from XML files above into .CSV file')
print('=====================================')
##
## Get current Time
curr_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
##
## Open a file - file gets created in CWD
outfile = "XML-Output-"+curr_time+".CSV"
fo = open(outfile, "a")
#
# Write field names
fo.write('UID;TITLE;ACTOR;DIRECTOR;COUNTRY;FORMAT;BITRATE;FPS;ASPECT RATIO;PATH'+'\n')
#
for item in List:
    ## Set Variables for XML parsing
    tree = ET.parse(item)
    root = tree.getroot()
    #print(root)
    product = root.find('uid')

    ##    
    ## Set Node variables   
    ##
    ## get UID
    if 'uid' in root.attrib:
        uid = root.attrib.get('uid')
    else:
        uid = ""
    ##
    ## Get title
    title = root[0].text
    ##
    ## Get actor
    actor = root[1].text
    ##
    ## Get director
    director = root[2].text
    ##
    ## Get country
    country = root[3].text
    ##
    ## Get elements inside ASSET node
    ##
    ## Get Format
    format = root[4][0].text
    ##
    ## Get Bitrate
    bitrate = root[4][1].text
    ##
    ## Get fps
    fps = root[4][2].text
    ##    
    ## Get Aspect ratio
    aspect_r = root[4][3].text
    ##
    ## Path = merge of Filepath + uid + format
    filepath = item
    #
    # Define extract + ignore ascii encoding
    line_extr = (uid + ';' + title + ';' + actor + ';' + director + ';' + country + ';' + format + ';' + bitrate + ';' + fps + ';' + aspect_r+ ';' + filepath + '-' + uid + '-' + format).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    ##
    ## Write output with line end character
    fo.write(line_extr + '\n')
    ##
fo.close()
print('')
print('*** Data extracted successfully! ***')
print('*** Check results in: '+ outfile + ' ***')
```

Comment: If this code is working, you may want to ask on [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow specializes in not working code.

Comment: "Any suggestions how to do it?" Yes, try it and see whether you get the basics down. Start by migrating everything into one class. Split everything into functions of that class. See whether it makes sense to keep it into one class or multiple classes. And voila, you're done. But you'll always have to start with creating a class and you haven't made that step yet. Once you've done that, we'll tell you that you really didn't want to use a for loop there. Take a look at what data types Python has in store by default.